# Applying a css class to the first image in my ngx-gallery-9 array

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ngx-gallery

I have this [ngx-gallery-9 stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-uzqt3b?file=src/app/app.component.ts) here and I'm trying to figure out how to apply a :first-of-type or nth-child(1) to 'fa-star' icon in the image gallery.

**Problem** - I want to color just the 1st 'fa-star' font awesome icon in the gallery. So just the 1st image is colored yellow.

I've tried a couple of different things but they all seem to apply the css to every icon or none of the icons, not just the first

couple of things I've tried below with no luck

```js
:host >>> ngx-gallery-action:first-of-type .fa-star:first-of-type {
      color: yellow;
}

:host >>> fa-star:first-of-type {
      color: yellow;
}

:host >>> .fa-star:nth-child(1) {
      color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use nth-of-type on the star, but on the first image(container), then the star,.

As the star will always be the first star in each container..

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-mttiqx?file=src%2Findex.html

so it will be:

```
.ngx-gallery-image:first-of-type .fa-star { color:#fc0; }
```

Comment: can you provide me with the answer in my stackblitz to assure it's working?

Comment: you can add the class with the inspector tool (F12) to see it works, but ill give it a go in stackblitz..

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-mttiqx?file=src%2Findex.html  there you go

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `nth-of-type' so something like this:

```
.fa-times-circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Edit: Try this code:

```
.ngx-gallery-icons-wrapper > .fa-times-circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I just tried and it still hides all of the icons, not just the first. I'm thinking it's something related to the library hiding and showing the images when selecting them.

Comment: @user1186050 what is the class of your first image? and also the class that is encasing your circles?

Comment: the first image has classes 'ngx-gallery-image ngx-gallery-active ngx-gallery-clickable ng-star-inserted' and the class wrapping the icon is 'ngx-gallery-icons-wrapper'

Comment: @user1186050 I've updated my answer. Please try the new code.

Comment: It didn't work, but thanks for the help. I'm going to try something else for now

Comment: @user1186050 alrighty, sorry I couldn't help.